# How to implement elasticsearch in a spring project?

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I have a spring project configured to use MySql database. Is is possible to implement elasticsearch for some search queries? Does anyone has a relevant experience or can point me to a good article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use Spring Data for Elasticsearch without having much Elasticsearch knowledge. Take a look at the toy project [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch).
Spring Data will help you on doing CRUD operations with an ORM approach.